# writing array in method

Tags: java, arrays, methods

In code I want to use two methods. In the first method I want to have the average of numbers of arrlist by taking arrlist as a parameter. In the second method, I want to calculate the standard deviation of the numbers of arrlist by taking arrlist and mean as parameters.

When I compile the code I get

```
error: method getAverage in class HW_PrimitiveArrays cannot be applied to given types;
error: method standardDeviation in class HW_PrimitiveArrays cannot be applied to given types;
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    double mean, sum;
    int[] arrlist = new int[] {5, 6, 4, 2, 9};

    System.out.println(getAverage(mean));

    System.out.println(standardDeviation(sum));
}


public double getAverage(int[] arrlist)
{
    double sum, mean;
    int i;
    sum = 0.0;
    mean = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < arrlist.length; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + arrlist[i];
    }
    mean = sum / arrlist.length - 1;

    return mean;
}


public double standardDeviation(int[] arrlist, double mean)
{
    double sum, temp;
    int i;
    sum = 0.0;
    temp = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < arrlist.length; i++)
    {
        temp = arrlist[i] - mean;
        temp = Math.pow(temp,2);
        sum = sum + temp;
    }

    sum = sum / arrlist.length - 1;
    sum = Math.sqrt(sum);

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You are calling the methods without passing the array parameter. Also, to be called from `main` the methods have to be `static`.

Comment: you need to pass the arrlist variable as parameter for getAverage method call. Like getAverage(arrlist);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as written, to call `getAverage` and `standardDeviation` from `main`, they must be declared `static`, because you're in a static context in `main`.

Second, pass the `int[]` you declared called `arrlist` to these methods.  You don't pass the return type; you pass the input.

```
mean = getAverage(arrlist);
System.out.println(mean);

System.out.println(standardDeviation(arrlist, mean));
```

Comment: The second method appears to take the result of the first as a second argument.

Answer (score 3):

Make you methods `static`, or instantiate an instance of your class and call your methods with the instance. Also, your arguments are incorrect. Since your first method takes an array, and your second appears to take the same array (and the result of the first method call) like

```
HW_PrimitiveArrays arr = new HW_PrimitiveArrays();
mean = arr.getAverage(arrlist);
System.out.println(mean);

System.out.println(arr.standardDeviation(arrlist, mean));
```

Comment: Good advice but I try not to use objects in this program.

Comment: @harold_finch Then those methods *must* be `static`.

Comment: Yeah, I changed them to static and wrote code from rgettman's answer and the program worked.

Comment: @harold_finch Also, one last note, arrays **are** objects in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the array to the method call, try:

```
System.out.println(getAverage(arrlist));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of your `main` code:

```
int[] arrlist = new int[] {5, 6, 4, 2, 9};
double mean = getAverage(arrlist);
double sum  = standardDeviation(arrlist, mean);

System.out.println(mean);

System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Standard deviation is not a sum.

Comment: I know sum is the just variable name.

Comment: I know, but I failed trying to understand why OP passes `sum` to `standardDeviation` in main.

Comment: I was using sum in the first method then I used it in the second method. I know it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Rename `sum` in `main` to `deviation` and your code will become awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an empty double into each method. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    double mean, sum;
    int[] arrlist = new int[] {5, 6, 4, 2, 9};

    mean = getAverage(arrlist);
    sum = standardDeviation(mean, arrlist);

    System.out.println(mean);
    System.out.println(sum);
}


public double getAverage(int[] arrlist)
{
    double sum, mean;
    int i;
    sum = 0.0;
    mean = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < arrlist.length; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + arrlist[i];
    }
    mean = sum / arrlist.length - 1;

    return mean;
}


public double standardDeviation(double mean, int[] arrlist)
{
    double sum, temp;
    int i;
    sum = 0.0;
    temp = 0.0;
    for (i = 0; i < arrlist.length; i++)
    {
        temp = arrlist[i] - mean;
        temp = Math.pow(temp,2);
        sum = sum + temp;
    }

    sum = sum / arrlist.length - 1;
    sum = Math.sqrt(sum);

    return sum;
}
```